# Custom UIApplicationShortcutIcon

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, 3dtouch

Is it possible to create custom UIApplicationShortcutIcon? Or only the one given by apple ?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is possible to UIApplicationShortcutIcon. According to docs:

> There are three types of quick action icon:
>
> 1. An icon from a system-provided library of common types, as described in the UIApplicationShortcutIconType enumeration
> 2. An icon derived from a custom template image in your app’s bundle and preferably in an asset catalog
> 3. An icon representing a contact in the user's address book, which you access through the ContactsUI framework (see ContactsUI Framework
>    Reference)

You can use `iconWithTemplateImageName:` to intialiaze new button. Eg:

```
- (void)createDynamicShortcutItems {

    // create several (dynamic) shortcut items
    UIApplicationShortcutItem *item1 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType:@"Item 1" localizedTitle:@"Item 1"];
    UIApplicationShortcutItem *item2 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType:@"Item 2" localizedTitle:@"Item 2"];
    UIApplicationShortcutItem *item3 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType:@"Item 3" localizedTitle:@"Item 3"];

    // add all items to an array
    NSArray *items = @[item1, item2, item3];

    // add the array to our app
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].shortcutItems = items;
}
```

Refer to [Apple Docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationShortcutIcon_Class)